# How to start a Rails server with an .sh script in a directory of choice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bash, scripting

I've been developing with rails for a year now, and although rails is pretty well automated, I'd like to take it one step further.

Every time i start working on a project, i open the terminal, cd to a project folder, than new tab in the terminal, then start the server with "rails s" then back to the first tab to run "sublime ." so that i load the folder in my text editor, Sublime Text.

What i would like is to create a .sh script that would do all that for me, but so far i haven't been able to make it start the server.

So, how to start rails server with a .sh script in a directory of choice?

Comment: well, i was trying to just run 'rails s' after cd-ing a couple of times in a script but that either leaves me stuck with a server output all over my main window, or if i run the server detached it's a pain to close, restart etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Manolo gave me an idea, so I've come up with this:

I modified my .bashrc as the following answer illustrates:

https://superuser.com/a/198022

Basically i added

```
eval "$BASH_POST_RC"
```

At the end of my .bashrc so i could run arbitrary commands after it was executed.

Next, i made a following script:

```
#launch_project.sh
#/bin/bash

cd <PROJECT DIR GOES HERE>;
firefox -P "development";
sublime . &;
gnome-terminal \
  --tab --title="Server" -e 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"rails s\";exec bash"' \
  --tab -e 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"git s\"; exec bash"';
```

That launches my development profile on firefox, my editor with a project root, and terminal window with two tabs - one that runs a WEBrick server, and another one which runs git status for me.

I made a desktop shortcut to the script so i have my own custom IDE of sorts :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd your_project_folder
nohup rails s > /tmp/rails_server.log 2>&1 &
sublime .
```

you can see the ouput of your rails server at the `/tmp/rails_server.log` file

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I've managed to soleve this in a similar way and i'll be posting the answer soon

Comment: If you are using rvm, you will need to have "#!/bin/bash"  as the first line of the script (not 'sh'), and then add "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm", then set your ruby choice with "rvm use x.x.x", then the "rails s" line.

Comment: rvm shouldn't have anything to do with the OS shell. Normally all un*x flavours should have a /bin/sh implementation. Most times it's a symbolic link to bash, ash, or whatever compatible kornshell in this unix.